# series from dictionary using pandas

Tags: pandas

#create series from dictionary using pandas

```
data_dict={'Ahmed':90,'Ali':85,'Omar':80}
series=pd.Series(data_dict,index=['Ahmed','Ali','Omar'])
print("Series :",series)
series2=pd.Series(data_dict,index=['Ahmed','Ali','Omar','Karthi'])
print("Series 2 :",series2)
```

I tried this code while practising pandas, I received the output as below:

```
Series :
Ahmed    90
Ali      85
Omar     80
dtype: int64

Series 2 :
Ahmed     90.0
Ali       85.0
Omar      80.0
Karthi     NaN
dtype: float64
```

Question: Why the data type got changed in the Series 2 from int to float?

I just tried to know what will be the output if i add an extra field in the index which is not belong to dictionary.I got NaN, but datatype got changed from int to float.

Comment: Because you have a missing value so Pandas fill it with `NaN` (a float "number") so Pandas have to "upcast" the dtype. If you want to maintain int representation, Pandas as a special dtype for that. Try: `series2=pd.Series(data_dict,index=['Ahmed','Ali','Omar','Karthi'], dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When providing a dictionary to `pandas.Series`, the keys are used as index, and the values as data.

In fact you only need:

```
series = pd.Series(data_dict)

print(series)
Ahmed    90
Ali      85
Omar     80
dtype: int64
```

If you use a list as source of the data, then `index` is useful:

```
series = pd.Series([90, 85, 80], index=['Ahmed','Ali','Omar'])

print(series)
Ahmed    90
Ali      85
Omar     80
dtype: int64
```

When you provide both, this acts as a [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
series = pd.Series(data_dict, index=['Ahmed','Ali','Omar','Karthi'])

# equivalent to
series = pd.Series(data_dict).reindex(['Ahmed','Ali','Omar','Karthi'])

print(series)
Ahmed     90.0
Ali       85.0
Omar      80.0
Karthi     NaN
dtype: float64
```

In this case, missing indices are filled with `NaN` as default value, which forces the float64 type.

You can prevent the change by using the `Int64` dtype that supports an [integer NA](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
series = pd.Series(data_dict, index=['Ahmed','Ali','Omar','Karthi'], dtype='Int64')
print(series)
```

Output:

```
Ahmed       90
Ali         85
Omar        80
Karthi    <NA>
dtype: Int64
```

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` is [considered a special floating point value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) ([IEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#NaN)). There is no value for `Karthi` in `series2`, so it gets automatically filled in with `NaN`. Try converting one of the integers into `np.NaN` and you will see the same behavior. A series that contains a floating point will be automatically cast as a floating point.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_dict = {'Ahmed':90, 'Ali':85, 'Omar':np.NaN} 

series = pd.Series(data_dict, index=['Ahmed','Ali','Omar'])
```

Output:

```
Ahmed    90.0
Ali      85.0
Omar      NaN
dtype: float64
```